# "Posts edited" on my profile is not the same as "edits" in users list

Tags: support, edits, profile-page

Here's my **Activity** view (on Ask Ubuntu) with **posts edited** highlighed.

[image]

This number is drastically different from **Revisions** which can be seen at the bottom left of the image, for reasons explained in answer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/posts-edited-count-on-profile-is-way-less-than-my-revsions-count), for example. I understand that difference OK - unlike **posts edited**, **revisions** counts retags, edits to my own posts and multiple revisions. I also know that **posts edited** doesn't include posts that were deleted later.

But why is the **posts edited** number different from [this one](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all), shown under the **Users** tab? (Hoping the other users whose data is in the image won't mind this being shown)

[image]

I'm pretty sure this number also shows attrition as posts are deleted, since I remember that the person who has 9995 edits in this image used to have 10000 in the same view.

I know this view is slow to update, but the difference between 9488 and 9873 seems quite a lot.

Are these two numbers counting something different? Why don't they match?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: A difference of almost 400, that's unlikely to be a caching issue.

Comment: @rene the difference is ~400, I doubt it's cached enough to be out that much. One is "posts edited" and the other is "edits", I'd guess multiple edits to the same post are counted in one number and not the other

Comment: Given it is on global/league like page I wouldn't be surprised if it only updates once in 24 hours but I admit to have such a large gap it must have missed a couple of cache invalidations in that case ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On your userprofile it says:

> [number] posts edited

while on the users/editors tab it says

> [number] edits

Those are really different things. Here is an [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/699304) to help me explain.

*Posts edited* depicts the number of (non-deleted) posts of **other users** that you edited at least once. There is no limit on how often you can edit a post.

*Edits* depicts the number of unique revisions that you have made of **other users** posts. A revision can encompass title, body and/or tags. You can have multiple revisions for a single post. Rollbacks also record a revision.

The number you see in the *revisions* tab of your profile are all revisions you made, including the ones on **your own** posts.

When I ran the above mentioned SEDE query this were the results:

```
distinct posts | 9224
---------------+-----
Edit           | 9694
Rollback       |   24
```

Given that the SEDE results are by now almost a week old and given that you're pretty active in editing, the numbers line-up enough to assume my analysis is sound, give or take caching ...

Comment: It should be noted that the "posts edited" count does not include edits that only modified tags.

Comment: This makes sense, @rene. However, in my case I have <500 distinct posts, but the copy editor badge. Is there more to it than this?

Comment: The wording is pretty confusing IMO.