# Is there an error in the Profile Impact query for History.StackExchange?

Tags: support

I noticed today great similarity between my Profile Impact summary on [History.StackExchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/2283/pieter-geerkens?tab=reputation)

[image]

and on [Stack Overflow itself](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1624450/pieter-geerkens?tab=topactivity)

[image]

The coincidence of both Posts Edited and People Reached being the same number despite the vastly different activity I have had on the two sites seems more likely to be a query error than reality.

**Update #1**

By my count the number of *edited posts* is way low on both counts. I estimate nearly 400 edited posts on Stack Overflow (20 pages @ 20 / page) and about 740 for History (37 pages @ 20 / page).

Comment: Manually migrated from [StackOverflow meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373213/is-there-an-error-in-the-profile-impact-query-for-history-stackexchange)

Comment: Cannot reproduce with my own profile ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui?tab=topactivity), [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/19545/fedorqui?tab=topactivity))

Comment: @fedorqui: Is your *Posts Edited* count remotely accurate? Mine is way low on both sites, factor of nearly 4 on SO itself and of 7+ on History.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No bug and no error, just coincidence.

According to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/history/query/863199/people-reached-v-2-approximately-accurate?UserID=2283#resultSets), on History.SE you reached 1,442,475 people and according to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/863199/people-reached-v-2-approximately-accurate?UserID=1624450#resultSets) the number is 1,444,056 for Stack Overflow. So while your activity might not be the same, by coincidence the views of questions you asked or answered sum up to about the same number.

As for the number of "posts edited" being very low, it's well explained in the answer to ["Posts edited" on my profile is not the same as "edits" in users list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298666/posts-edited-on-my-profile-is-not-the-same-as-edits-in-users-list). (TL;DR: it shows only edits to posts written by **other people**.)

Comment: I guess it's a good day to buy a lottery ticket. ;-)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens it is indeed! ;)